# Unable to add event listener to webNavigation.onCompleted

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Using the mock function below along with the dev console:

This call will work:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(processWebNavChange, filtera);
```

but when I actually pass in my real `var filter` it throws this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Could not add listener`

My actual data looks like this:

```
{
    url: [ {hostContains: ".im88rmbOwZ"} ]
}
```

```
function registerWebNavListener() {
    var matchers = getUrlMatchers();
    var filter = {
        url: matchers
    };
    // test with mock data filtera that actually works
    const filtera = {
      url:
      [
        {hostContains: "example.com"},
      ]
    }
    if (matchers.length > 0) {
        chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(processWebNavChange, filtera);
    }
}

async function processWebNavChange(data) {
}
```

Is there something wrong with my data structure that I'm actually using? I don't believe that the filter object I returned is incorrect
}

**EDIT**:
I added a new

```
const filterb = {
        url: [ {hostContains: ".im88rmbOwZ"} ]
    };
```

and it still fails with that.  The single entry `{hostContains: ".im88rmbOwZ"}`, was the first item returned from getURLMatchers() which I used as an example of real data being returned.

Comment: Judging by ```\"``` your real data is already stringified, which is a mistake, typically caused by using stringify with chrome.storage or sendMessage. Set a breakpoint in devtools and actually inspect the data in the debugger, not in console.

Comment: Sorry, I should have deleted that part of the post:  The real data is here according to the debugger:  {
    url: [ {hostContains: ".im88rmbOwZ"} ]
}

Comment: There must be an entry in the real data that is bad. You can isolate it by dividing the list in two and trying the first half, then the second half. Continue this division process until you find the culprit.

Comment: I had tried it with my real data by creating a mock structure with "{
    url: [ {hostContains: ".im88rmbOwZ"} ]
}"  and it also fails.

Comment: The problem is caused by the uppercase letters `O` and `Z`.

Comment: it looks like the uppercase was the problem, but I don't think I saw mention of this in the docs anywhere (nor could I see a hint of it in the chromium source when I went to try to find more hints as to my errors there). Is this something I just missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comment on the upper-case letters was the cause of the issue. Converting everything to lowercase resolved the problem.

Although, I am not clear as to why that was a problem to begin with. (If there are any hints in the chromium source code event filter handlers, I'd appreciate it if it could be pointed out).